# What can I use for a water supply for my electric hot water heater?

Tags: plumbing

I want to move my hot water heater to the porch by my washing machine.  Can I use the same water supply lines that are used for my washer?

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, it's possible. Practically, it depends on the size of the pipes, distance, and layout of your plumbing. If the water main is 3/4" and the washing machine is fed by 3/8" lines, you'll lose a lot of flow going out and back. Depending on the type of valve on your shower, it could mean significant temperature swings when a toilet is flushed or another shower is running, or you could see the flow frequently drop to a trickle to avoid freezing you. It could also mean much longer waits before hot water reaches various fixtures.